# Execute login command manually closed the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, authentication, terminal

I have executed 'login' command in bash shell from root account which closed the shell
But, if i execute the same 'login' command in bash shell from non -root account, it is asking for username & password again

And idea why the shell is closed from root account?

**Update :** I logged in via putty as root and tried executing login, the connection was closed. I also tried executing the same in a terminal opened in VNC workspace
I tried from non-root accounts via putty & VNC workspace which worked

My shell & OS details :

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Its depends on your server permission for root with respect to shell.

Comment: is it possible to check the permissions set for the root? any command available? can i change those rules?